# Vue2 how to check if one of optional inputs are filled

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

```
<template>
  <v-layout
      @drop.prevent="addFiles"
      @dragover.prevent
  >
    <ValidationObserver
        ref="observer"
        v-slot="{ invalid }"
    >
      <form class="topic-form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <ValidationProvider
          v-slot="{ errors }"
          name="Name"
          rules="max:255"
        >
          <v-textarea
              class="my-2"
              color="primary"
              rows="4"
              v-model="topicText"
              :counter="255"
              :error-messages="errors"
              @paste="pasteFiles"
              label="Enter message"
          ></v-textarea>
        </ValidationProvider>
        <upload-files />
        <v-btn
            color="primary"
            class="my-2"
            type="submit"
            :disabled="invalid"
        >
          Create
        </v-btn>
      </form>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

I have such vue component and it uses another component called UploadFiles. I need to check if either one of topicText or file  are present in form while submitting. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `$ref` in the `UploadFiles` to get any data from this component.